# Setup with promtail + loki + grafana is not showing any log data

Tags: grafana, loki

In a setup with promtail, loki and grafana, no data shows up in grafana explore. All three parts are running on the same machine.

Question is: where to look for an error in the setup?

## Promtail

promtail.yaml:

```yaml
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /var/db/promtail/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://127.0.0.1:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: varlogs
      __path__: /var/log/**/*log
```

This *seems* to be fine. Testing:

> promtail --config.file=promtail.yaml --log.level=info -print-config-stderr

```
---
# Loki Config
# (version=, branch=, revision=unknown)
global:
  file_watch_config:
    min_poll_frequency: 250ms
    max_poll_frequency: 250ms
server:
  http_listen_network: tcp
  http_listen_address: ""
  http_listen_port: 9080
[...]
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:24.711575585Z caller=promtail.go:133 msg="Reloading configuration file" md5sum=169d8cc02367d196d7ba24694ea90c5d
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:24.712927375Z caller=server.go:322 http=[::]:9080 grpc=[::]:32729 msg="server listening on addresses"
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:24.713264874Z caller=main.go:174 msg="Starting Promtail" version="(version=, branch=, revision=unknown)"
level=warn ts=2023-12-13T16:00:24.713474024Z caller=promtail.go:263 msg="enable watchConfig"
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.714075081Z caller=filetargetmanager.go:361 msg="Adding target" key="/var/log/**/*log:{job=\"varlogs\"}"
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.716662721Z caller=filetarget.go:313 msg="watching new directory" directory=/var/log/loki
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.716703277Z caller=filetarget.go:313 msg="watching new directory" directory=/var/log/promtail
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.716812088Z caller=filetarget.go:313 msg="watching new directory" directory=/var/log/gitea
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.716857702Z caller=filetarget.go:313 msg="watching new directory" directory=/var/log/grafana
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.717132151Z caller=filetarget.go:313 msg="watching new directory" directory=/var/log/redis
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.717201082Z caller=filetarget.go:313 msg="watching new directory" directory=/var/log/caddy
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.717280021Z caller=filetarget.go:313 msg="watching new directory" directory=/var/log
ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.720424446Z caller=log.go:168 level=info msg="Seeked /var/log/caddy/caddy.log - &{Offset:606936482 Whence:0}"
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.720534804Z caller=tailer.go:145 component=tailer msg="tail routine: started" path=/var/log/caddy/caddy.log
ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.720631282Z caller=log.go:168 level=info msg="Seeked /var/log/gitea/gitea.log - &{Offset:8194 Whence:0}"
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.72066379Z caller=tailer.go:145 component=tailer msg="tail routine: started" path=/var/log/gitea/gitea.log
ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.720728343Z caller=log.go:168 level=info msg="Seeked /var/log/grafana/grafana.log - &{Offset:38901 Whence:0}"
level=info ts=2023-12-13T16:00:29.720756759Z caller=tailer.go:145 component=tailer msg="tail routine: started" path=/var/log/grafana/grafana.log
[...]
```

## Loki

loki.yaml

```yaml
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096

common:
  instance_addr: 127.0.0.1
  path_prefix: /var/db/loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /var/db/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /var/db/loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

query_range:
  results_cache:
    cache:
      embedded_cache:
        enabled: true
        max_size_mb: 100

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h
```

The loki application / service is up and running. Anything else I could be testing here?

## Grafana

Data source for loki created with:

- Type: Loki
- URL: `http://127.0.0.1:3100`
  (everything else: left at default settings)

Looking at grafana's `/explore` only leads to no data being shown, even without any filter criteria. Pressing `Run query` just doesn't seem to have any effect.

The grafana log looks good to me:

> tail /var/log/grafana/grafana.log

```
logger=grafana.update.checker t=2023-12-13T16:31:16.759743533+01:00 level=info msg="Update check succeeded" duration=486.885735ms
logger=cleanup t=2023-12-13T16:41:16.24610575+01:00 level=info msg="Completed cleanup jobs" duration=13.483743ms
logger=plugins.update.checker t=2023-12-13T16:41:16.617294501+01:00 level=info msg="Update check succeeded" duration=334.848905ms
logger=grafana.update.checker t=2023-12-13T16:41:16.657803737+01:00 level=info msg="Update check succeeded" duration=387.307337ms
logger=cleanup t=2023-12-13T16:51:16.240282272+01:00 level=info msg="Completed cleanup jobs" duration=7.750284ms
logger=grafana.update.checker t=2023-12-13T16:51:16.292110778+01:00 level=info msg="Update check succeeded" duration=21.261137ms
logger=plugins.update.checker t=2023-12-13T16:51:16.313163122+01:00 level=info msg="Update check succeeded" duration=31.295959ms
logger=cleanup t=2023-12-13T17:01:16.220217724+01:00 level=info msg="Completed cleanup jobs" duration=4.195714ms
logger=plugins.update.checker t=2023-12-13T17:01:16.312587838+01:00 level=info msg="Update check succeeded" duration=30.754461ms
logger=grafana.update.checker t=2023-12-13T17:01:16.333881656+01:00 level=info msg="Update check succeeded" duration=63.366615ms
```

Pointers on what might be missing here are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explore for Loki without any query doesn't suppose to provide anything: you are expected to provide [a valid query](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/).

You can try something like `{host=~".+"}`, as a starting point.

---

See this two examples:

- [No query](https://play.grafana.org/explore?panes=%7B%22qgf%22:%7B%22datasource%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22,%22queries%22:%5B%7B%22refId%22:%22A%22,%22expr%22:%22%22,%22queryType%22:%22range%22,%22datasource%22:%7B%22type%22:%22loki%22,%22uid%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22%7D%7D%5D,%22range%22:%7B%22from%22:%22now-6h%22,%22to%22:%22now%22%7D%7D%7D&schemaVersion=1&orgId=1)
- [Proposed query](https://play.grafana.org/explore?panes=%7B%22_Dh%22:%7B%22datasource%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22,%22queries%22:%5B%7B%22refId%22:%22A%22,%22expr%22:%22%7Bhost%3D%7E%5C%22.%2B%5C%22%7D%22,%22queryType%22:%22range%22,%22datasource%22:%7B%22type%22:%22loki%22,%22uid%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22%7D,%22editorMode%22:%22code%22%7D%5D,%22range%22:%7B%22from%22:%22now-6h%22,%22to%22:%22now%22%7D%7D%7D&schemaVersion=1&orgId=1)

Comment: Thanks, very good pointer. Also, the example link shows it pretty well. "My" grafana requires at least 1 label filter, though. However, the respective filter dropdown only shows "No options found". Fow now, I don't see how to make that label filter optional. But as play.grafana shows, that seems to be possible. Need to find more time to invest.

Comment: @Windowlicker, what do you mean? Any Loki requires at least on label in a selector. You cannot use selector without labels (or no selector at all): that what demos supposed to show.

Comment: Oh, labels are required? (Maybe, Loki isn't as clean and simple as expected. Maybe for this "a couple of services on a single server"-setup over here, a mere "tail -f" and "grep" are a valid solution.)

Comment: Well, this is only for you to decide. On the other hand you'll have a couple labels like `host` and probably `filename` anyway, so I don't see how selector like `{host=~".+"}` (or `{filename=~".+"}`) might be a problem. @Windowlicker

Comment: Valid point. According to the Grafana over here, Loki doesn't have any labels. Or at least there is no results for `=~".+"` on any possible label. As the Promtail output above looks good (to me), a look into what's received by Loki might be suitable. Any chance of doing that? Besides staring at Grafana's /explore?

Comment: Just realized that Loki is logging some warnings with "Per stream rate limit exceeded". Sounds like a good cause for not having any data for any label. Will check https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/request-validation-rate-limits/